yum not updating packages, process times out
I have an Oracle Linux server that was originally installed at OEL7. Recently, it was upgraded to OEL 8. The repos are hosted on a Red Hat Satellite server. Other OEL hosts are not presenting this error - even ones have also been upgraded from OEL 7 to OEL 8.
It's now presenting the following issue:
When I run yum update --downloadonly it gets a list of packages to update but then, after I enter "y" to get the downloads to start, it reports:
[MIRROR] kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://satellite_host/repos/Org_Default/Library/custom/Oracle_Linux_8/Oracle_Linux_8_x86_64_BaseOS_Latest/Packages/k/kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]

And then it repeats three times and then report [FAILED]
What I've done so far:

yum clean all
Had netnwork assist in packet tracing. Result was that communications were happening and the channel was closed with a FIN ACK.
Red Hat wasn't much help other than to say it looked like a network issue (They don't support the OEL clients)
Reboots
Play with configuration around the timout setting
Increased log level and tried again. Logs only show initialization routines. Compared to a host that is working, which had a lot more information.

What I may try tomorrow is to mount the ISO for OEL 8 and try an update that way.
Question - Have any of you seen this type of behavior? It seems to be pointing at yum and associated bits as the culprit. Any suggestions for resolving this?
Appreciate any help. I'm running out of hair to pull...

Does this just affect that one file or many? What happens when you try to download the package manually using curl https://satellite_host/repos/Org_Default/Library/custom/Oracle_Linux_8/Oracle_Linux_8_x86_64_BaseOS_Latest/Packages/k/kernel-4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64.rpm?

You might try re-regeristing the OEL server to the redhat sattelite again.   This can be done with subscription-manager commands,  but exact ones depend on your server.

@bxm I tried the curl and it just sat there. I tried the same command on a host that I know does work, and it gave the same results.

@user103944 Oracle hosts aren't registered with Satellite - just Red Hat hosts. We only use Satellite for managing the repos.

Try with curl --verbose and see if the additional logging points the way. Upgrading in place can be sketchy, though I wouldn't expect something like this. If you have it working on another host with the same OS, I would go for a clean install, personally.
